# How to find period of functions involving greatest integer function [.]

Tags: functions

How to find period of functions involving greatest integer function [.]

1)   $[x+1/2]+[x-1/2]+2[-x]$

2)   $[x]+[x+1/3]+[x+2/3]-3x+10$

Hints will suffice.I'm not being able to approach these problems without a graphical approach.Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separating it into two cases will give you the answer.

- $x=N+\alpha$ where $N$ is an integer and $\alpha$ is a real number such that $0\le \alpha\lt \frac 12$.
- $x=N+\alpha$ where $N$ is an integer and $\alpha$ is a real number such that $\frac 12\le \alpha\lt 1$.

For (2), you can separate it into three cases : $0\le\alpha\lt \frac 13,\frac 13\le \alpha\lt \frac 23,\frac 23\le \alpha\lt 1$.

**Added** : 
For (1)

- For $x=N+\alpha$ where $0\le \alpha\lt\frac 12$, the function can be simplified as $(N+1)+N+2(-N-1)=-1$.
- For $x=N+\alpha$ where $\frac 12\le \alpha\lt 1$, the function can be simplified as $N+(N-1)+2(-N-1)=-3$.

Hence, the period is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part observe that
$$
[x+1/2]+[x-1/2]+2[-x]=2([2x]-[x])-1+2[-x]
$$

For the second observe that
$$
[x]+[x+1/3]+[x+2/3]-3x+10=[3x]-3x+10=\{3x\}+10
$$
But the function $\{x\}$ has period $T=1$, hence the above function has period $T=1/3$.

Comment: @Mann What is "not regular" about the function? Are you referring to the vertical lines in the graph? How do you know that those are not merely artifacts of inexact computation in the graphing software?